# Poincare inequality for the measure of Brownian path

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis

I am wondering if the Poincare inequality holds for the Brownian path space.

As the simplest example, let $\{w_t, t \in [0, 1]\}$ be a 1-d standard BM: has independent increments and continuous paths, $w_0 = 0$, , $w_t - w_s \sim N(0, t - s)$ for $t > s$.

Let $E$ be the the collection of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ with $v(0) = 0$. Of course, $w$ derives a probability measure on $E$, said $\mu$.

Let $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which can be continuously extended to some Frechet differentiable function on $L^2[0, 1]$. By $Df$ I only mean the Frechet derivative.

So my question is that for all $f$ satisfying the condition above, does the following inequality holds with some finite constant $C$: 
$$\int_E f^2d\mu \leq C\int_E \|Df\|^2d\mu. $$

Comment: In this context I think it's more usual to consider the Malliavin derivative (and its Cameron-Martin norm) instead of Frechét.  The Poincaré inequality does hold in that case (of course you have to restrict to $f$ with $\int f\,d\mu = 0$).  You can find this, and an involved discussion of the many notions of differentiability (which I have not taken the time to unwind) in Chapter 5 of V. Bogachev's book *Gaussian Measures*.

Comment: Note also that in the case mentioned by Nate the log-Sobolev inequality holds as well, which gives you quite a bit more than the Poincaré inequality.